# Java Unparseable date: "Fri Nov 10 22:50:46 EET 2017" exception

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get "dd.MM.yy H:m" pattern of a date.

And I use the code given below

```
String dDate = "Fri Nov 10 22:50:46 EET 2017";
DateFormat dfr = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
Date cDate = dfr.parse(dDate);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy H:m");
String result =  df.format(cDate);
lastSyncDate.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.last_backup) + " " + result);
```

And I get 
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Nov 10 22:50:46 EET 2017" exception.

I cannot solve it and I think it is about DateFormat pattern.

Thank you for your solvings.

Comment: What happens if you replace `EET` with `UTC`?

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Date` class.  Please find a backport for the `java.time` package and use the appropriate class for your use case.

Comment: Also, I ran your code (at least on my PC) and it works fine.

Comment: @JoeC I agree about using Joda, but just in case it's you, "try not to use this outdated API" isn't a reason to downvote a clearly-presented question.

Comment: @enesigneci *Try* it in this example and see what result you get. The problem might be that `EET` is not a recognized time zone.

Comment: @chrylis I tried it and it works. But now, how i can use EET or how to convert it to gmt+3?

Comment: You'll need to describe the platform where it's failing in detail; it appears that your database of time zones is deficient, and the best way to fix it will depend on specifics (including, probably, the Android version).